# multiple image in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to upload multiple image in angular.i have uploaded multiple image but when i click submit button i could get my files name in my console like
[image]

my view page like

```
<form ng-submit="save()"><input type="file" name="images" id="images" ng-model="images" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(event)" multiple><input type="submit"></form>
```

my controller like below

```
$scope.files = [];
$scope.imageUpload = function(event){
    var files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {            
        var file = files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.files.push(e.target.result);
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);         
    }
}
```

when i click submit button my code look like below and my console looks like in above picture

```
$scope.save = function(){
console.log($scope.files);
}
```

how can i send all selected images to php file in angularjs?

Comment: whats the expected, and what are you currently getting as resp?

Comment: when i upload multiple image i want to preview and when i click submit button all uploaded file value get in the php